# Python : How to center Label in tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to construct a popup window, containing varying text message for user to respond.

I seek a way to center the text (Label) and Button inside that window- with no success.

[image: Popup window]

Popup Window has a determind size. Centering the frame inside it should take into account width and height of textlabel ( defined in amount of letters ).

As you can see in code, `w`, `h` defines window's size, `xbias`,`ybias` have an expression to center `testframe` (both contains `alpha1`, `alpha2` as a correction factor for text's size )

I'm seeking the mathematical expression for `alpha1`, `alpha2` ( which equal for 1 for now )... or a better way to construct such a popup window.

```
root = Tk()
w = '400'
h = '100'
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(w, h))
root.configure(bg='lightgreen')

txt = StringVar()
txt.set("This is an error message")

alpha1 = 1
alpha2 = 1
xbias = int(w) / 2 - (len(txt.get()) / 2) * alpha1
ybias = int(h) / 2 - alpha2

testframe = ttk.Frame(root)
testframe.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=ybias, padx=xbias)

label1 = ttk.Label(testframe, textvariable=txt)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered using the `.pack()` method instead for this. You could achieve the desired effect far easier that way:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
top = Toplevel(root)

w = '400'
h = '100'
top.geometry('{}x{}'.format(w, h))

frame = Frame(top)

label = Label(frame, text="This is an error message")
button = Button(frame, text="Ok")

frame.pack(expand=True) #expand assigns additional space to the frame if the parent is expanded
label.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

After some research, doing this with grid is an awful lot easier than expected, see below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = '400'
h = '100'
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(w, h))

label = Label(root, text="text")
label.grid(column=0, row=0)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

If we assign `.rowconfigure()` and `.columnconfigure()` a `weight` which is not `0` then the specified row and column will expand to fill the space given to it in the window.

Comment: thanks for you answer. since my entire GUI is using `grid`, I quite sure that mixing with `pack` is not a good idea. second - your example doesn't constrain a size for window's root and acutally the size of the frame will be the minimal as the text's ( you can delete `expand=True` and you will get the same affect - which is none regarding frame's size ). I'm looking for expanding/ centering `testframe` inside `root`

Comment: Mixing two different methods in the same window is not a good idea no, but I figured that as this was an error message you'd be placing it in a `Toplevel` widget rather than your `root`. I was not constraining a size for the window however I now have. That's simply not true, removing `expand=True` does not have the same result. You're confusing `expand` with `fill`. Fill will give the widget additional internal space, expand gives the widget additional external space. My code produces a window with a set size where the internal frame is centered, how is that different from what you need?

Comment: first- you are correct regarding mixing up `fill` with `expand`.
second - after giving determined size to the windows- I see the difference.
third - altough it is a popup windows, and i guess you are right again regarding mixing `grid` and `pack` this time - are you familiar with a way doing it using `grid` ?

Comment: I don't know any way of doing this with `.grid()` off the top of my head. I imagine you'd need to calculate the size of the window and then using `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` in order to set a specific size to the window.

Comment: calc window size...is not needed since I determind it. what I need to know - is how to calc row's size in pixels... as i tried to explain in my question :(

Comment: You have a starting window size, but windows can be expanded. Whilst you're using 400x100 to begin with, there's nothing to stop the user grabbing the corner and stretching it out to 1000x1000.

Comment: you are right, but I can prevent it ( didn't put it in my code... yet ). still remain the dimensions of the text label

Comment: @Guy.D I've added a way to do this with `.grid()`

Comment: If this answers your question then can you mark it as accepted so that future users can learn from this too.

Comment: I have a slow mouse :)

Comment: my cat catches slow mice

Answer (score 0):

A way to center **Frame** inside root window can be done in this manner:

> Part A) Create A window with a specific size `h`, `w` (since it is a
>   popup - in this example I disable resizing it ). Inside the frame- a
>   `Label` and a `Button`:

```
root = Tk()
w = '200'
h = '80'
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(w, h))
root.configure(bg='lightgreen')    ###To diff between root & Frame
root.resizable(False, False)

txt = StringVar()
txt.set("This is an error message")

testframe = ttk.Frame(root)
testframe.grid(row=0, column=1)

label1 = ttk.Label(testframe, textvariable=txt)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)

ok_button = ttk.Button(testframe, text="OK", command=root.destroy)
ok_button.grid()
```

> Part B) In order to get frame's dimensions ( including `Label` and
>   `Button` inside ) we use `testframe.update()` and then
>   `testframe.winfo_width()` `testframe.winfo_height()` to obtain frame's
>   updated values. `xbias` and `ybias` calculates the center to place the
>   frame in the middle:

```
testframe.update()

xbias = int(w) / 2 - testframe.winfo_width() / 2
ybias = int(h) / 2- testframe.winfo_height() / 2
testframe.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=ybias, padx=xbias)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what you did to make the frame centered. You presented a lot of code, but for a beginner it would be hard to know what code is related to the centering and what is not. Also,this solution won't keep the frame centered when you resize the window.

Comment: @BryanOakley -   since most of code is same as the question- I tought it is quite understandable and there is a title "## Update testframe's dimentions". 
i'll add more annotations to make it more understandable

Comment: Yeah, but that means that the reader has to go line-by-line, comparing your code to the original code to see what is different, which is error-prone.

Comment: I undestand- and now ?

Comment: In my opinion it's still no better. You need to have a description _outside_ the body of code, not just some inline comments. Also, forcing the window to a specific size in order to hide the fact that the frame doesn't stay centered isn't a very good solution in my opinion.

Comment: I respect your opinion- still it is a popup window ( which I think it is fair enough to disable resizing it ). can you refer for a better annotation of code ?

Comment: I think what Bryan's trying to say is that you're not clearly explaining what your code is doing and your code is "bloated" in the sense that there's a lot of stuff there which isn't necessary to resolve the problem you outlined in your question. Also, disabling resizing is fine, but think about future proofing. If you decided to go in and add more elements or change the window size then it'll be a lot harder to update everything because it's hard coded.

Comment: OK . can you refer me to a better explained code ? or something more understandable ?

Comment: This might help you https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Comment: @BryanOakley - I hope this is better explained.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I've found that using the `anchor` makes it easier to center a label in the window.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
w = 100
h = 100
root.geometry(f"{w}x{h}")

label = Label(root, text="text")
label.place(anchor=CENTER, relx=0.5, rely=0.5)

root.mainloop()
```