# How do I center a label in Tkinter using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label, center

I started creating a simple game using tkinter and encountered a problem. I search the internet but could not find an answer. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to center a label in tkinter. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import * #Imports TK Interface
import time #Imports Time Module
welcome = Tk() #Opens the Welcome window
welcome.title("Start Up") #Names the Wqelcome window 'StartUp'
welcome.config(bg = "gray") #Changes the Welcome windows background color to beige
nameLabel = Label(welcome, text="Welcome", bg="gray", fg="white")#Creates the welcome label
```

If you know how to center labels in tkinter, please answer. Thanks!

Comment: `pack(side="top")` or use the `grid()` method

Comment: Cool I'll make an answer then.  : )

Comment: By any chance, do you know of any way to position a label/button in the direct center of the window?

Comment: I don't know myself but I found a post that does mention it.  See my answer below for link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter has two options to show widgets

`grid()` or `pack()`

**Using `pack()`:**

*In this case this is probably the best option -since you are dealing with only 1 widget:*

By default `top` and `bottom` will align a widget to the center. Left and right will align to the left and right respectively.

Here an extract of your code demonstrating this property:

```
nameLabel = Label(welcome, text="Welcome", bg="gray", fg="white") 
nameLabel.pack(side="top")
```

You can also center align text at the bottom as well:

```
nameLabel = Label(welcome, text="Welcome", bg="gray", fg="white")
nameLabel.pack(side="bottom")
```

**Using `grid()`:**

Sometimes it may become necessary to align multiple widgets.  You can position them individually and accurately using `grid()`:

```
nameLabel1 = Label(welcome, text="Welcome", bg="gray", fg="white")
nameLabel1.grid(column=0, row = 1)
nameLabel2 = Label(welcome, text="Welcome", bg="gray", fg="white") 
nameLable2.grid(column=1, row = 1)
nameLabel3 = Label(welcome, text="Welcome", bg="gray", fg="white")
nameLabel3.grid(column=2, row = 1)
```

*Update:* Further to your centring label in window comment I do not know how to do this myself although I have found [this post that seems to do what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46069531/python-how-to-center-label-in-tkinter-window)

Comment: there is a third method, `place`. In fact, if you want to place a single widget in the center of some other widget, it's often the best choice.

Comment: @BryanOakley  I didn't know that, could you please consider making an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't really suggest using layout managers and widget instantiations in the same line like that when trying to assign the widget(s) to a variable, as they would in fact be `None`.

Comment: Configuring `side` option has no influence over centering the widget in any way for me, are you certain what you claim is true?

Comment: @Nae Please try the following and you will see what I mean: `from tkinter import *`, 

`welcome = Tk()`, 

`welcome.title("Start Up")`, 

`welcome.config(bg = "gray")` ,

`nameLabel = Label(welcome, text="Welcome", bg="gray", fg="white")`,

`nameLabel.pack(side="top")`,

`left = Label(welcome, text="Welcome", bg="gray", fg="white")`,
`left.pack(side='left')`,
`right = Label(welcome, text="Welcome", bg="gray", fg="white")`,
`right.pack(side='right')`,
`another=Label(welcome, text="Welcome", bg="gray", fg="white")`,
`another.pack(side='left')`,

Comment: @Nae Could I see your script that did not work as well?

Comment: @Simon I'm not saying that with top or bottom is not centered, I'm saying they're redundant. A simple pack() does as much centering as they would.

Comment: @Nae  Oh I see.  Yes they do.  Thank you.  I'll edit my post later.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of placing a single widget in the center of another widget, `place` is the best choice. It has options to locate a widget relative to another widget (usually, but not necessarily, relative to its parent).

In your case, you want the center of the label in the center of its parent. You can use a relative X coordinate of .5, a relative Y coordinate of .5, and an `anchor` of "center", meaning that the center of the widget is placed at the given coordinates.

Example:

```
nameLabel.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")
```

Comment: When the `Label` widget contains only "text", the `place` method works well. However, when the `Label` contains an image, although the `Label` will still be centered, a bad side effect is that the entire window collapses upon itself to a few pixels wide. Can you share how to overcome this window size collapse?

Comment: In this instance, is for example `welcome.geometry('100x100+0+24')` the only way to go to solve this side effect?

Comment: @SunBear: the disadvantage to `place` is that it won't affect the size of the containing window. It is up to you to set the size of the containing window. That is one of the main reasons I rarely recommend `place`. Sometimes that behavior is exactly what you want, but for most widgets in most circumstances it is not what you want.